# how to join part of two table, rather than whole

Tags: mysql

i was just wondering that in case we have two tables in Mysql and both have millions of records.
so we want to join part of two table. how can we accomplish that.
according to me if we use limit then it first queries all records and then limit the result.
will appreciate your suggestions. thanks

consider there are two tables.
user:(id in autoincrement)
id, name, email, gender

user_actions:(user_id is foreign key here)
id, user_id, action_id, action_date

we need to query actions for user but not all at a time, as the data is huge in the tables

Comment: post your code (table create statements and queries)

Comment: edited my post .hope this will help u understand my question

Comment: @rajesh, why do you want to check limited records. Let MySQL do what it's best at. Even if both your tables have millions of records, you can run the JOIN on both tables and have MySQL query the desired results for you. And don't forget to use the right indexes

Comment: thanks abhay, but i was checking for the efficient way to do this. in a way which will not take the mysql down due to a huge query. but yes indexing helps. any other way along with index ?

and if we use LIMIT, will it take all records first and then chooses first 10 (for example) or it doenot query whole table and only gives first 10

Comment: Well @rajesh, The main reason why MySQL could be down due to a query could be a poorly written query and poor indexing. I'm not sure how LIMIT works but I'm sure MySQL (or any other DB engine) should be smart enough to not take all records and then retrieve 10. By the way, what is it you are trying to do? Rather than asking how to join parts of table, you should ask a more direct question on what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should add an index on the date field, and then use a where clause to say less than one date and greater than another. The index should allow you to not search through all records in the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WHERE clause to limit the records used in the join.  You'll have to provide more details about how you want to choose the part of the table if you want more details.

Comment: but this way it will check all the records for the where clause to match. i want to check limitted records

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the result to end user you can use a paging strategy to show the result page by page (50 rows per page for example).
You can use limit keyword of mysql to produce each page.

you can find the example [here](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm).